# webpack working with font

Tags: javascript, express, webpack

I am trying to use webpack2 with express, and I just can't seem to make my font served, js file works fine,  please,help
this is my webpack.config

```
const devConfig = {
devtool: '#source-map',
entry: [
    './public/js/entry.js',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
]
,
output: {
    filename: './js/main.js',
    path: '/',
    publicPath: publicPath
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?'
        }
    ]
}
```

};

and inside my scss file, I have this

```
src: url('../font-files/firasans-extralightitalic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../font-files/firasans-extralightitalic-webfont.woff') format('woff');
```

}
and my path structure
[image]

while I keep getting this error

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../font-files/firasans-extralightitalic-webfont.woff2'

can anyone tell me what's wrong...I see some others add there fonts in js file, but I really don't like do it that way

Answer (score 1):

ok, I've struggle another couple hours, now, I find out how to make it work.
the idea is we write relative path in @font-face, but the path is relative to the entry, in my case, the entry is style.sass, so I wrote this

```
src: url('./font-files/firasans-extralightitalic-webfont.woff2')
```

now I can resolve this files correctly